# Using MonoTouch with subclassed UIViewControllers don't bind as expected

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I've tried this from a couple of different approaches, but this isn't working as expected. This is a hybrid iOS application, with about half of the screens UIViewControllers with a primary UIWebView. There is a lot of logic that is similar for handling the UIWebView events, especially around error handling. The subclasses are slightly more specialized to deal with the screens that are presenting. So, the class diagram is roughly:

```
UIViewController
  +- BaseWebController   <-- this class should bind to UIWebView
      +-- ScreenAController
      +-- ScreenBController
      +-- ...
```

Where the BaseWebController.designer.cs is really basic. In fact, once wired up it looks like:

```
[Register ("BaseWebController")]
partial class BaseWebController
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWebView WebView { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (WebView != null) {
            WebView.Dispose ();
            WebView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: I get various exceptions because the UIWebView is not properly bound to the WebView instance. I get various messages such as *'Failed to find selector setWebView: on ScreenAController'*, but it boils down to (I think) that it's trying to bind the parent class (ScreenAController) and fails.

**Question: Am I missing something in how this binding is supposed to work? Essentially I am trying to keep this very DRY and push all of the duplicate code to the base class. Otherwise I'll end up repeating the same 100 lines of wire up code and error checking for each screen.**

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stuart:

Right. I ended up somewhere very similar to what you mention. I decided to have each parent class (ScreenAController, ScreenBController) bind to the same view and implement an abstract property defined by the base:

```
   protected abstract UIWebView ActiveWebView { get; }
```

And that base class sets the xib file in its constructor. ScreenAController, ScreenBController, ..., implement the property which is really just a reference to that outlet. Its as DRY as I could get. Which is pretty much what you're saying.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to the base class to handle most error handling.
    /// </summary>
    protected override UIWebView ActiveWebView { get { return this.WebView; } }
```

@mhutch, I'll take a closer look at that bug. I can work around this for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you are right about the inheritance and binding not quite gel'ing.

Can you compromise perhaps by adding:

```
[outlet]
new UIWebView WebView
{
    get { return base.WebView; }
    set { base.WebView = value;}
}
```

to each of the ScreenController classes.

Not perfectly DRY but better than duplicating everything across all classes.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like this bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1449#c7